# Asp button without submit

Tags: asp.net, button, submit

I have an asp:button in my user interface, this button is to close the session and destroy the cookies, but I don't want this button to be the submit type, because when I type something in any asp:TextBox and push enter my button fires and closes my interface.

Is there some way to have an asp:Button "type button" like in HTML, without the submit function, which lets me close my session, and when I press enter don't fire the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<input type="button" id="inputID" runat="server" />
```

it ll be generated in your codebehind as `HtmlInputButton`;